# Sides created by angle bisector

Tags: geometry

If I have triangle ABC with side lengths a,b,c, and I have an angle bisector coming out of point A, which divides side a into two sections at intersection point P, what is the length of BP and PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well known property of bisector. $\frac{BP}{CP}=\frac{AB}{AC}$. So you have a system

$\frac{BP}{CP}=\frac{b}{c}$ and $BP+PC=a$

The solution to the system is $BP=\frac{ac}{b+c}$ and $CP=\frac{ab}{b+c}$

Comment: @user123706 Just to confirm, you know about the angle bisector theorem?

Comment: I do now, yes. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have enough information to solve each of the two triangles you get. For example, for $\Delta ABP$, you have the angles $\tfrac{1}{2}A$ and $B$, and the side $b$. Probably the easiest approach is to find the third angle (using angle-sum=$180^\circ$) and then use the law of sines.